# Why use and instead of or in mybatis to check a empty stirng or null

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have 2 conditions (m_name is emptystirng and m_name is null)

so, I wanted input sql query only m_name has a value.

but

```xml
<if test="m_name !=''or m_name !=null">
```

above setenece is not worked.

so I found below and then it's worked

```xml
update menu01 
<set>
<if test="m_name !=''and m_name !=null">
    m_name = #{m_name}
</if>
```

but I cannot understand why using 'and'.

because if it is null. it cannot be emptystring because it is null.

please let me know.

sorry for my english.

please please help me.

thank you

Comment: You just need a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)  When `m_name` is `null`, `m_name != ''` returns `true`. When `m_name` is an empty string, `m_name != null` returns `true`. So, if you use `or`, the condition always returns `true`.

Comment: you are right! I was just confused!  as your advice , I  wrote logic about this then I realized I'm a fool . thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It happens to all of us 